# Spaces with same homotopy type and deformation retract

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces that have the same homotopy type. Show that $X$ and $Y$ can be embedded as deformation retracts in the same space.

I'm having trouble getting anywhere with this one. Since $X$ and $Y$ have the same homotpy type, there are continuous maps $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ such that $f\circ g$ is homotopic to $1_Y$ and $g\circ f$ is homotopic to $1_X$. But i'm really not seeing how to use this. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to have a look at Corollary 0.21 in http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf